# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component issue in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using react-native-cli version `2.0.1` and react-native version `0.57.8`. I am learning React native, and have encountered an issue when trying to render two different child components (`Header` and `AlbumList`) in the main `App` component.

**Issue**

[image]

The error disappears if I remove the `<View>` tags and `AlbumList` component in the index.js file (meaning only show one component). I have looked through threads like [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20084), but am still unable to identify how I'm using the `<View>` tag incorrectly.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import AlbumList from './src/components/AlbumList';

//>Create a component
const App = () => (
<View> <Header headerName={'Albums'} /> 
<AlbumList />
</View>

);


//>Render component on device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', ()=> App);
```

**AlbumList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const AlbumList = () => {
return (
  <View><Text> Album List </Text></View>
);
};

export default AlbumList;
```

I think the issue isn't anything to do with the Header.js file, but sharing code nonetheless.

**Header.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'; // The view tag allows us to position and wrap elements

// Make a component
const Header = (props) => {

  const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style = {viewStyle}>
      <Text style = {textStyle}> {props.headerName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      height: 60
  },

  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
};

export default Header;
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you write in the component/index.js ?

Comment: I have an index.js in the root, and its contents are in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your index.js file, replace App function with below,

```
//Create a component
const App = () => (
  <View><Header headerName={'Albums'} /><AlbumList /></View>
);
```

there should be no space between components here

while using react native components, try to put each element in a new line, in this way you don't have to worry about spaces

```
const App = () => (
      <View>
        <Header headerName={'Albums'} />
        <AlbumList />
      </View>
    );
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know what the syntax would be if I didnt want to worry about spaces? I tried this and it didnt work -


const App = () => {
return (
    <View>
<Header headerName={'Albums'} />
<AlbumList />
</View> 


);

};

Comment: @KeshavVasudevan, I updated the answer with the preferred syntax. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks a ton @farid!

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had a misplaced semicolon as shown and it was giving me so much headache

```
 <Screen>
        <RestaurantScreen />; //Make sure you have no misplaced semicolon like in my case here
      </Screen>
```